# How to say the car has no more gas

Tags: phrase-choice, sentence-choice

> I have run out of gas.
>
> I am run out of gas.
>
> My gas is over.
>
> My gas is finished.

Which of these (if any) is a normal way to tell someone I have no more gas?

Comment: 'I have run out of gas/petrol' is correct. The other three are incorrect. You could say 'I have used up all the gas/petrol'.

Comment: You can say *My car has run out of gas*. You can also say *I have run out of gas*, but note that this can also mean *I have run out of energy,* where the *I* refers to the speaker of the sentence and not his/her car. Context usually clears things up

Answer (score 4):

> I have run out of gas

is the only one that is correct.

You can say *I am running out of gas* if you notice your gas is low while you are traveling, or you can say *I am out of gas* if you want to tell someone you have little to no gas in youbr car right now.  *I am run out of gas* is ungrammatical and sounds awkward.

*Over* and *finished* don't sound right.  You can use these terms to describe something running out of *time*, or a process/event whose time is ending.  You can also say you've finished something if you've eaten or used all of something.  But a car doesn't "finish" gas, nor is it's gas "over" - the term that comes to mind is it "uses up" gas.

Comment: You can also say, "I am out of gas", which wasn't on the list but is quite common.

Answer (score 3):

The correct statement for the first example would be simply, I *ran* out of gas, past tense. I've run out of gas, before, past perfect, would indicate you've run out of gas several times in the past. I'd run out of gas, before, indicates it happened to you once, before.

Second example, I'm running out of gas, means you haven't run out of gas, yet, but the supply is low. The needle on the gas gauge is near the E.

The last two examples are never used. Typically, one would say, I'm out of gas.

Comment: Here's another way of stating the last two examples. My gas tank is empty.